# Eclipse Kepler Crashes on Start up only shows splash screen

Tags: eclipse, window, eclipse-kepler

I currently am using Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7.  Previously I could get to the workspace screen to apply which workspace I wanted to use but for some reason as I start Eclipse I now get the Kepler's spash screen for maybe a 10th of a second and the application crashes. I search the Eclipse folder for logs to determine what was the problem but I did not find and logs.  Has anyone experienced issue like this?  I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 18):

Loading the eclipse with -clearPersistedState option worked for me

Answer (score 2):

After trying some tricks such as eclipse -clean, or eclipse -debug -console, searching for hints in the log files, removing xulrunner from the java.library.path environment, deleting some of the most recent history files and so on I found the solution. In your workspace directory perform the following steps:

```
cd .metadata/.plugins
mv org.eclipse.core.resources org.eclipse.core.resources.bak
Start eclipse. (It should show an error message or an empty workspace because no project is found.)
Close all open editors tabs.
Exit eclipse.
rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources (Delete the newly created directory.)
mv org.eclipse.core.resources.bak/ org.eclipse.core.resources (Restore the original directory.)
Start eclipse and start working.
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I only get to the Eclipse Splash screen.  I can not get into my workspace using eclipse.  I tried to cd .metadata/.plugins but I don't have a .metadata directory.  Within my plugin directory I have found a jar "org.eclipse.core.resources_3.8.100.v20130521-2026" not sure if I should move this jar to a back up.   I am running within a Windows environment so I'm kind of curious of the Unix commands.  I have also tried the -clean option.  But again I can not find a log file within the Eclipse directory.

Comment: I did get this when attempting to run eclipse on the command line with the -debug and -console option  -Djava.class.path=C:\EclipseForMoss\Eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Comment: Do what I did. Curse yourself for having the foresight to backup all your projects beforehand, but not enough to backup your IDE. I had to download and reinstall all over again, which is hair tearingly fun but sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Both files

*workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/1300.snap

workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus/26522e0d83a422eed93329ece7565cfc/_58.cfs*

had each several 100MB of size,
after deleting those eclipse started again.